# How to remove last character of the string using tSQL?

Tags: t-sql

All i need is to remove last character which is comma (,) in this case.

I tried `Substring, Left, and Right` functions but they need **length of the string**.

Here is the scenario:-

```
select 
(Case col1 & 1 When 1 Then 'Case 1,' Else '' End)  + 
(Case Col2 & 2 When 2 Then 'Case 2,' Else '' End)  +
(Case Col3 & 4 When 4 Then 'Case 4,' Else '' End)  
as Case
from table_01
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, just don't remove the last comma. Remove the *first* one instead:

- using [`STUFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

  ```
  SELECT
    STUFF(
      (CASE col1 & 1 WHEN 1 THEN ',Case 1' ELSE '' END)
      + (CASE col1 & 2 WHEN 2 THEN ',Case 2' ELSE '' END)
      + (CASE col1 & 4 WHEN 4 THEN ',Case 4' ELSE '' END),
      1,
      1,
      ''
    ) AS [Case]
  FROM table_01
  ```
- using [`SUBSTRING()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

  ```
  SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
      (CASE col1 & 1 WHEN 1 THEN ',Case 1' ELSE '' END)
      + (CASE col1 & 2 WHEN 2 THEN ',Case 2' ELSE '' END)
      + (CASE col1 & 4 WHEN 4 THEN ',Case 4' ELSE '' END),
      2,
      999999  /* not necessary to calculate LEN()-1, any value
                 that is definitely greater than that will do */
    ) AS [Case]
  FROM table_01
  ```

Comment: beautiful. I give you another 23K (wish i can).

Comment: fantastic! With SUBSTRING I had to repeat the whole expression but using STUFF() is much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following, which uses the length minus one to give you the length you want:

```
declare @string varchar(50)

set @string = 'testing, testing, testing,'

select substring(@string, 1, len(@string) -1)
```

results:

```
testing, testing, testing
```

Edit:

You can use the following:

```
select substring(c, 1, len(c) -1)
from
(
  select 
    (Case When col1 = '1' Then 'Case 1,' Else '' End) +
    (Case When Col2 = '2' Then 'Case 2,' Else '' End) +
    (Case When Col3 = '4' Then 'Case 4,' Else '' End)  
    as C
  from t
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12eea/6)

Comment: How about if without declaring variable?

Comment: you would replace the @string variable with your value.

Comment: bluefeet, please see the question above again. I am concatenating fields in select statement. I already used substring but how to define length of the concat string

Comment: @user1327064 see my edit. You can either make it a subquery or you can repeat the CASE statement in the substring

Comment: Thanks but piece of query in my question is just 5% of whole stored procedure. It really hard to repeat where cluase again in subquery

Comment: @user1327064 then wrap it in another query so you can use the value you have returned already